# No reaction initially when browsing in new Tab in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

At work, I mostly use Chrome for all work where a browser is required. We use Google enterprise, just so you know I can't control all settings.

Earlier this year, I first encountered a problem: If I a open a new tab in chrome, it takes > 10 seconds to start loading. This is true for a URL, chrome settings or a search string.
<strike>Once the initial page loads, I don't see any further impact on performance in that tab.</strike>
I noticed now, that many other things are slower than before, e.g. working in GMail, starting a new search in Google Search, even if I reuse an already "working" tab. The factor is not as big as when opening a new tab, but noticable.

I tried all things mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/43449/google-chrome-is-slow?s=5%7C0.2909) and on several other help sites.

I can fix it - temporarily - in asking our IT to disable virus scanner (Kaspersky Endpoint Security) for a minute, then enable it again.
It always works then. Sometimes for a few minutes or a few hours or once for two weeks without any problems.

I couldn't figure out anything special I did every time the problem returned - or at least whenever I thought I found a common thing, it turned out to be not reproducible.

Interestingly, I observe at the same time it happens in Chrome that also Opera v30.x and latest Iron browser are affected (all using Blink engine I believe). 
Firefox is completely unaffected.

Just to mention a few things I tried, to have them written down explicitly:

- Reinstall Chrome from scratch without current bookmarks (there is a known issue regarding bookmarks and performance it seems) or extension.
- Restart computer after deinstall and install.
- Disabled all extensions.
- Deinstalled all extensions.
- Start Chrome as Administrator
- Start Chrome with command line --in-process-plugins
- Disabled "DNS prefetching..."
- Disabled "Predict network actions..."
- Try open a new incognito tab instead of normal tab
- Disabled Hardware Acceleration

Now I'm out of ideas and hope someone is out there with a few more.

I'm running a Windows 7 x64 Professional, Core i7, 16GB RAM, SSD.

Comment: You have identified the cause of this issue - Kaspersky. It's not under your control and bypassing Kaspersky is impossible by design, so you have to talk with people who can do something about it.

Comment: I am the only one in the company experiencing this - as far as IT can tell. It works also when KAV is enabled again as mentioned. Thus KAV may be part of the problem, but it is not the sole thing.

Comment: what about `chrome://plugins` ? and `disable the Hardware Acceleration` in advanced settings?

Comment: right. disable Hardware Acceleration I also tried. Will add it to the list.
what about chrome://plugins?