# Chrome is very slow on Windows 10

Tags: windows, google-chrome, delay

I have Chrome, Firefox, and Edge on my PC, and Chrome is the slowest of them all. It's not slow to actually connect to the web or load webpages, but there's a 5-10 second delay before it will start loading a page. This isn't a network connection problem, because it happens even with the Settings and About pages.

I've googled this problem and tried several things to fix it, but none of them have worked. I've tried disabling hardware acceleration, disabling all my extensions, resetting Chrome's settings, clearing browsing data, and resetting Winsock (`netsh winsock reset`). This problem also isn't specific to Windows 10, because it happened in Windows 8.1 before I upgraded. Any ideas what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Possible dupe of [Google Chrome is Slow](http://superuser.com/q/43449)

Comment: I tried all of the suggestions mentioned there and none of them helped.

Comment: So what version of Chrome did this start happening within precisely?

Comment: I don't know because I've had the problem ever since I installed Chrome on my PC a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware acceleration on Chrome enabled by default. It increases browser performance by enhancing some processes, But as mentioned before, it can clash with some app processes and create issues like slowing down the application process. Follow below instruction to turn off chrome hardware acceleration feature :

Step 1: Type chrome://settings on the chrome URL bar and press enter

Step 2: Scroll down Click “Advanced“

Step 3: Under the “System” tab, you can see an option “Use hardware acceleration when available“. Switch the toggle to turn it off. The toggle will turn grey when it is disabled. And a button will show up “Relaunch“.

[image: See this image]

Step 4: Click the button relaunch, it will restart the browser with disabling hardware acceleration feature.

Or you can check [this site](https://allbestreviews.net/chrome-slow-on-windows-10/). They provided 8 methods :